# Mesh doesen't convert to quads?

Tags: modeling, topology

So I have a mesh which I tried to beautify, and convert to Quads (<kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>J</kbd>), but nothing works. Is it because the mesh was joined together before-hand? I don't get it.

[image]

Comment: Hello, Often when importing from other softwares the faces are actually disconnected. Try merging the vertices in edit mode, with everything selected, right click, merge, by distance

Comment: did you remember to select all of the vertices before you typed alt-j?

Comment: Yes, all the vertices were selected before ALT + J. @Gorgious I did have the mesh as a .smd (It's just a game engine model format, don't mind it.) I imported it in and yeah, tried ALT + J and  Beautify.